# Cytoscape.js - How to create a graph with weights for implement Dijkstra?

Tags: shortest-path, cytoscape.js

I am trying to create a graph with nodes and edges from scratch. I am creating nodes and edges like in the codes below but I can not see anything on the page. Here is my html and codes in it. I want to use Dijsktra adding weights to edges, but until now, I can not see anything on the browser.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Tutorial 1: Getting Started</title>
    <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
        var cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
            elements: [{
                    data: {
                        id: 'a'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'b'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'c'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'd'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'e'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: {
                        id: 'ab',
                        source: 'a',
                        target: 'b'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'da',
                        source: 'b',
                        target: 'd'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'bd',
                        source: 'b',
                        target: 'd'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'eb',
                        source: 'e',
                        target: 'b'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'ba',
                        source: 'b',
                        target: 'a'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'ed',
                        source: 'e',
                        target: 'd'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'ce',
                        source: 'c',
                        target: 'e'
                    }
                    data: {
                        id: 'bc',
                        source: 'b',
                        target: 'c'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body and html tags aren't closed, for one.  The [Cytoscape tutorials](http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/tutorials/) assume basic understanding of HTML, CSS, and JS.  If you're having trouble with the basic [getting started tutorial](http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/2016/05/24/getting-started/), then I suggest reviewing the [Mozilla web tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials) first.

Things to keep in mind:

- Make sure your tags are balanced.
- Make sure your external (e.g. script) refs are correct.
- You can't do proper web dev without running a web server, e.g. [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).
- It's easier to start from an example file in a tutorial verbatim, rather than trying to change things first.
- The code for the [demos at the top of the docs site](http://js.cytoscape.org/) can also be good starting points.